# How would you optimize this MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

Can anybody help me in optimizing this query,

```
SELECT(X1,      
    X2   
FROM TABLEAA   
 WHERE   
        Y IN (SELECT Y FROM TABLEBB WHERE Z=SELECTED)   
    AND Y  IN  (SELECT Y  FROM TABLECC  WHERE ZZ=SELECTED)    
)
```

WHERE AS

```
TABLEAA : 1 million enteries    
TABLEBB : 22 million enteries    
TABLECC : 1.2 million enteries
```

it works but take too much time, almost 30 sec

Is there any other way to right this?

edit: the Z and ZZ are totally two different column

Comment: Certainly changing this to using joins and proper indexes on your columns would reduce the execution time.

Comment: How on earth can anybody create or maintain a table with x million entries without any PK/FK ?

Comment: Just curious, could we get a post on what the run time improved too @wiki?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `JOINs`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    A.X1,      
    A.X2   
FROM TABLEAA A
   JOIN TABLEBB B ON A.Y = B.Y AND B.Z='SELECTED'
   JOIN TABLECC C ON A.Y = C.Y AND C.Z='SELECTED'
```

Also, make sure you have the appropriate indexes on A.Y, B.Y and C.Y.  You may find a better performance by adding indexes on you Z columns -- this depends on your table structure and several other factors.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using subqueries, join TABLEBB and TABLECC to TABLEAA, and check for ZZ=SLECTED in your WHERE clause, for both joined tables.

Make sure the columns that participate in the outer joins are indexed.

Comment: Wouldn't optimizer optimize subqueries in the same way?

Comment: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/15/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-sql-server/ --- it could even 3 years ago, couldn't it?

Comment: @zerkms: I didn't read the whole article, but perhaps some of the columns are nullable.  I don't think it's as simple as you think it is; subqueries are notorious for being slower than their joined counterparts.

Comment: nullability shouldn't affect `IN` (I don't work with sql server for years, but I would be surprised if it doesn't optimize `IN (subquery)` well). And in this case subqueries aren't even correlated

Answer (score 0):

Indexes...

- Add an index to `Z` in `TABLEBB`
- Add an index to `ZZ` in `TABLECC`
- Add an index to `Y` in `TABLEAA`

Comment: Actually for `TABLEBB` it would be a good idea to have a composite `(Z, Y)` index. The same for `TABLECC`

Comment: Not sure that would help as it would still need to scan every row where `Z = SLECTED`.  But I could be wrong.

Comment: @D Stanley: If you have `Z` index - DBMS finds the row id first then fetches the data. If it has everything in the index - it doesn't need to perform a lookup over data (as it's already available in the index)

Comment: Clever - I would do that with an INCLUDE in MS-SQL.

Comment: @D Stanley: oh, that's a nice extension didn't know that (don't work with sql either ;-) But may be worth mentioning that in the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT X1, X2 FROM TABLEAA 
JOIN TABLEBB ON Y = Y JOIN TABLECC ON Y = Y 
WHERE TABLEBB.Z = SLECTED && TABLECC.ZZ = SLECTED
```